# SPRING PetClinic: BatchError when trying to delete vets with foreign key to visits

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb

I got an assignment to extend the SPRING petclinic application (forked from this repo: https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-rest ). One assignment is to "Show all visits by a vet".

For that I added a foreign key and a column to the table `visits` to the hsqldb:

```
...
CREATE TABLE visits (
  id          INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  pet_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
  vet_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
  visit_date  DATE,
  description VARCHAR(255)
);

ALTER TABLE visits ADD CONSTRAINT fk_visits_vets FOREIGN KEY (vet_id) REFERENCES vets (id);
ALTER TABLE visits ADD CONSTRAINT fk_visits_pets FOREIGN KEY (pet_id) REFERENCES pets (id);
CREATE INDEX visits_pet_id ON visits (pet_id);
...
```

Edited the `visit` model accordingly:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "visits")
public class Visit extends BaseEntity {
...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "vet_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Vet vet;
...
```

And added the `vetId` to `#/components/schemas/Visit` in `openapi.yml` too:

```
    Visit:
      title: Visit
      description: A booking for a vet visit.
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/VisitFields'
        - type: object
          properties:
            id:
              title: ID
              description: The ID of the visit.
              type: integer
              format: int32
              minimum: 0
              example: 1
              readOnly: true
            petId:
              title: Pet ID
              description: The ID of the pet.
              type: integer
              format: int32
              minimum: 0
              example: 1
              readOnly: true
            vetId:
              title: Vet ID
              description: The ID of the veterinarian.
              type: integer
              format: int32
              minimum: 0
              example: 1
              readOnly: true
          required:
            - id
            - vetId
            - petId
```

I am able to build and run the project, but when I try to delete a `vet` I get the following error message:

```
{
  "className": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException",
  "exMessage": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [FK_VISITS_VETS]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
}
```

So I tried to Override the generated `delete` method from `Vet` to FIRST delete all corresponding `Visit`s and THEN delete the `Vet`:

```
public class SpringDataVetRepositoryImpl implements VetRepositoryOverride {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void delete(Vet vet) {
        Integer vetId = vet.getId();
        this.em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Visit visit WHERE vet_id=" + vet.getId()).executeUpdate();
        this.em.createQuery("DELETE FROM Vet vet WHERE id=" + vet.getId()).executeUpdate();
        if (em.contains(vet)) {
            em.remove(vet);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run it now I get an error that I don't understand, nor have the slightest idea what it could mean:

```
{
  "className": "org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException",
  "exMessage": "Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: delete from vets where id=?; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: delete from vets where id=?"
}
```

Neither the `vet`, nor it's `visits` got deleted. Does anyone has a guess why?
My current project state can be found here: https://github.com/Fabian-Anna/java-petclinic/tree/user-story-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key that references the vets table prevents deleting any row in that table which is referenced from the visits table.

You can define the foreign key with ON DELETE CASCASE which will cause all the referencing visits to be deleted if a row in the vets table is deleted.

See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_constraints

BTW you do not need to create an index on the visits table. The foreign key creates its own index.

Comment: Even after adding `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the foreign key `fk_visits_vets` I get the same error :(
I noticed the following Warning in my IntelliJ Console:
`INFO  AbstractBatchImpl - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Warning Code: -1100, SQLState: 02000
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - no data`

Comment: With ON DELETE CASCADE you do not need to override the generated delete method. The delete will happen automatically and you won't get the first error message that you reported.

Comment: You are right! Thank you so much! It still baffles me that I need to change this in the SQL Script during initialization, since the `fk_visits_pets` foreign key hasn't specified this and it still works. The `pet.delete` method is overriden in the exact same way I defined the `vet.delete` method.